# swift change struct model into another model if have similar id

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I get the response from the api as in the JSON code below

```
{
    "timestamp": 1632838801,
    "status": "ok",
    "message": "ok",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "id_category": 6,
            "products": [
                {
                    "id": 12,
                    "product_name": "product one",
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "id_category": 6,
            "products": [
                {
                    "id": 20,
                    "product_name": "product two"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "id_category": 13,
            "products": [
                {
                    "id": 994,
                    "product_name": "product three"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

}

I'm success to decode the response into a struct like this:

```
struct ProductDataResponse {
    let timestamp: Int
    let status: Int
    let message: String
    let data: [Data]
}
struct Data {
    let id: Int
    let idCategory: Int
    let products: [Product]
}
struct Product {
    let id: Int
    let productName: String
    let idJelajah: Int
}
```

the problem is, I want my data model different from the response, if the data has the same id_cateogry then the existing product data will be grouped into the same id_category,below i attach the expected result of struct  and the expected json.
the result is 2 array of diffrent id_category and product

```
struct ListCategory {
    let idCategory
    let category: [Category]
    
}
struct Category {
    var id: Int
    var product: [Product]
}
struct Product {
    let id: Int
    let productName: String
    let idJelajah: Int
}



{
    "timestamp": 1632838801,
    "status": "ok",
    "message": "ok",
    "data": [
        {
            "id_category": 6,
            "products": [
                {
                    "id": 12,
                    "product_name": "product one",
                },
                {
                    "id": 20,
                    "product_name": "product two"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id_category": 13,
            "products": [
                {
                    "id": 994,
                    "product_name": "product three"
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to make for loop to check if the model Data.categoryId have duplicate, then i insert diffrent cateogrId into another model, and i success make two data & remove the similar cateogryId, but i'cant move the product object to new model where the category id is belong

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With model being:

```
struct ProductDataResponse: Codable {
    let timestamp: Double
    let status: String
    let message: String
    let data: [Data]

    struct Data: Codable {
        let id: Int
        let idCategory: Int
        let products: [Product]
    }
    struct Product: Codable {
        let id: Int
        let productName: String
    }
}

struct ProductDataOutput: Codable {
    let timestamp: Double
    let status: String
    let message: String
    let data: [Category]

    struct ListCategory: Codable {
        let idCategory: Int
        let category: [Category]

    }
    struct Category: Codable {
        var id: Int
        var product: [Product]
    }
    struct Product: Codable {
        let id: Int
        let productName: String
    }
}
```

Side note, to be working with your current code, I changed `timestamp` into a `Double` & `status` into a `String`, else it would cause decoding issue.
I also put them inside each other, to avoid naming. For instance, you'd need to differentiate `Swift.Data` & `ProductDataResponse.Data`, and the two `Products` would collide.
Also, I added a top level structure that you didn't give: `ProductDataOutput`.

And a helper for converting Product into Product (ie the one with structure of the response, and the one with the target one). Of course, we could use the same struct, but I wanted to separate them, just in case as you wrote it yourself.

```
extension ProductDataOutput.Product {
    init(with otherProduct: ProductDataResponse.Product) {
        self.id = otherProduct.id
        self.productName = otherProduct.productName
    }
}
```

The following code is inside a

```
do {
    //HERE
} catch {
    print("Error: \(error)")
}
```

That I'll skip, but keep it for debugging and catch issue.

Let's parse into the model as the Response first:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
let parsed = try decoder.decode(ProductDataResponse.self, from: Data(initialJSONStr.utf8))
print(parsed)
```

Then, I'd use `reduce(into:_:)` to group by category id the products.

```
let reduced = parsed.data.reduce(into: [Int: [ProductDataOutput.Product]]()) { partialResult, current in
    var existing = partialResult[current.idCategory, default: []]
    let newProducts = current.products.map { ProductDataOutput.Product(with: $0) }
    existing.append(contentsOf: newProducts)
    partialResult[current.idCategory] = existing
}
print(reduced)
```

Then, let's create our target structure. I used a quick `map()` to transform the `reduced` into a `[ProductDataOutput.Category]`.

```
let output = ProductDataOutput(timestamp: parsed.timestamp,
                               status: parsed.status,
                               message: parsed.message,
                               data: reduced.map { ProductDataOutput.Category(id: $0.key, product: $0.value) })
```

Then, to debug the output as JSON (as it's the sample you gave):

```
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
encoder.keyEncodingStrategy = .convertToSnakeCase
encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
let encodedOutput = try encoder.encode(output)
print(String(data: encodedOutput, encoding: .utf8)!)
```

With this, you should be fine.

Comment: when create the output with parsed data, i need to mapping it first, the data
becam double

   let output = parsed.map { item in
                    ProductDataOutput(id: String(item.timestamp),
                                      timestamp: item.timestamp,
                                               status: item.status,
                                               message: item.message,
                                               data: reduced.map
                                               { ProductDataOutput.Category(id: $0.key, product: $0.value) })
                }

Comment: Indeed. I put the two `timestamp` as `Double`, because a timestamp as `Double` usually make more sense that using a String for it... But that's minor since the "big" issue was the products/categories mapping.

Comment: what should i do if i want to add more value inside ProductDataOutputCateory like this

 struct Category: Codable {
        var id: Int
        var categoryName: String

        var product: [Product]
    }

Comment: It depends. From where do you get the `categoryName` in the "initial decoding"?

Comment: i got it from the data struct

 struct Data: Codable {
        let id: Int
        let categoryNamy: String
        let idCategory: Int
        let products: [Product]
    }

so when the the reduce function start, i also want the categoryName to appear 

 data: reduced.map { ProductDataOutput.Category(
                                                id: $0.key,
                                                categoryName: HERE
                                               product: $0.value) })